# MySQL Add and subtract based on Alias value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, mariadb

I have a query calculating `SUM()` based on enum value IN/OUT (see below)

[image]

I'm trying to extend the calculation and add a second `SELECT` based on the 
`TOTAL IN` and `TOTAL OUT` outputs using this formula:

> ***BUDGET + TOTAL IN - TOTAL OUT = TOTAL PROFIT***

The problem is that the output is wrong (see below)

[image]

It should be `£17,408.90`

The query I'm trying to extend is:

```
SELECT
  f.id_festival AS ID,
  CONCAT('£ ', FORMAT(f.festival_budget, 2)) AS Budget,
  CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment IN' THEN p.pmt_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)) AS `TOTAL IN`,
  CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment OUT' THEN p.pmt_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)) AS `TOTAL OUT`,
  (SELECT
      CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(f.festival_budget + 'TOTAL IN') - 'TOTAL OUT', 2))) AS PROFIT
FROM festival f
  INNER JOIN payment p
    ON p.id_festival = f.id_festival
WHERE f.id_festival = 1
GROUP BY f.id_festival
```

I can't figure out where that 115.000 came from. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your 'Total In' and 'Total Out' are not decimal values as they have '£ ' appended to them. Use columns from 'payment' table instead of them. It should work then.

Comment: is only one column with IN/OUT value that why I use a CASE before this...

Comment: Perhaps `JOIN` inflated the number of rows that `SUM` saw, leading to an excessive total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need for sub select :

```
SELECT
  f.id_festival AS ID,
  CONCAT('£ ', FORMAT(f.festival_budget, 2)) AS Budget,
  CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment IN' THEN p.pmt_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)) AS `TOTAL IN`,
  CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment OUT' THEN p.pmt_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)) AS `TOTAL OUT`,
  CONCAT('£ ', 
    ROUND(
        f.festival_budget 
        +ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment IN' THEN p.pmt_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)
        -ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment OUT' THEN p.pmt_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)
        , 2)
    ) AS `PROFIT`
FROM festival f
  INNER JOIN payment p
    ON p.id_festival = f.id_festival
WHERE f.id_festival = 1
GROUP BY f.id_festival
```

Comment: that's wonderful just a misplaced "2". works perfect thanks a lot.. I was scratching my had in last 2 days....

Comment: @Gallex NP ;) As Gordon said, you can't use alias in MySQL/maria : they are only generated as a post processing. You'll need to redo the same functions you used to make the value of the alias. (where is the mistake ? I want to correct it)

Comment: just before AS `PROFIT` instead of  "END)), 2)) AS `PROFIT`" it works with "END), 2), 2)) AS PROFIT".

Comment: @Gallex ok, this one should be OK ;)

Answer (score 2):

`'Total In'` is a string.  If you use it in a numeric expression, then MySQL converts it to a number.  And that number is `0`.  The string `'Total In'` has nothing whatsoever to do with the column whose alias is `Total In`.

In MySQL, you basically have two choices for using a table alias in an expression:  (1) Repeat the expression.  (2) Use a CTE.

```
SELECT f.id_festival AS ID,
       CONCAT('£ ', FORMAT(f.festival_budget, 2)) AS Budget,
       CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment IN' THEN p.pmt_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)) AS `TOTAL IN`,
       CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment OUT' THEN p.pmt_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)) AS `TOTAL OUT`,
       CONCAT('£ ',
              ROUND(f.festival_budget +
                    SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment IN' THEN p.pmt_amount
                             WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment OUT' THEN - p.pmt_amount
                             ELSE 0
                        END),
                    2)
             ) AS PROFIT
FROM festival f INNER JOIN
     payment p
     ON p.id_festival = f.id_festival
WHERE f.id_festival = 1
GROUP BY f.id_festival;
```

It is true that under some circumstances you can use an alias in a subquery for the same effect.  But I don't recommend that, because I have not found the documentation that guarantees that this will work.

Comment: You'll have the wrong answer if you add the output without making it negative, no ? using `'Payment OUT' THEN 0 - p.pmt_amount` to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
 SELECT
  f.id_festival AS ID,
  CONCAT('£ ', FORMAT(f.festival_budget, 2)) AS Budget,
  CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment IN' THEN p.pmt_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)) AS `TOTAL_IN`,
  CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment OUT' THEN p.pmt_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)) AS `TOTAL_OUT`,
  (SELECT
      CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(f.festival_budget + 'TOTAL_IN') - 'TOTAL_OUT', 2))  AS PROFIT
FROM festival f
  INNER JOIN payment p
    ON p.id_festival = f.id_festival
WHERE f.id_festival = 1
GROUP BY f.id_festival
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but same output 115.000

Comment: 'SELECT
  f.id_festival AS ID,
  CONCAT('£ ', FORMAT(f.festival_budget, 2)) AS Budget,
  @TOTAL_IN := CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment IN' THEN p.pmt_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)) AS `TOTAL_IN`,
  @TOTAL_OUT := CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment OUT' THEN p.pmt_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)) AS `TOTAL_OUT`,
  (SELECT
      CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(f.festival_budget + @TOTAL_IN) - @TOTAL_OUT, 2))  AS PROFIT
FROM festival f
  INNER JOIN payment p
    ON p.id_festival = f.id_festival
WHERE f.id_festival = 1
GROUP BY f.id_festival'

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
 SELECT ID, Budget, `TOTAL IN`, `TOTAL OUT`, CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM((Budget   + `TOTAL IN`) - `TOTAL OUT` ))) AS PROFIT FROM 
 (SELECT f.id_festival AS ID, 
 CONCAT('£ ', FORMAT(f.festival_budget, 2)) AS Budget,
 CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment IN' THEN   p.pmt_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)) AS `TOTAL IN`,
 CONCAT('£ ', ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN p.pmt_type = 'Payment OUT' THEN   p.pmt_amount ELSE 0 END), 2)) AS `TOTAL OUT`,
 FROM festival f
 INNER JOIN payment p
 ON p.id_festival = f.id_festival
 WHERE f.id_festival = 1
 GROUP BY f.id_festival) a;
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but now the Profit is 0. but at least now I can try in a different way..